# NodeJS and ECMA Script version

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a Nodejs (8.x) project and wonder which version of ECMA script I can use. As far as I understood I can even use ECMA Script 2017 (without a transpiler like Babel) because 99% of the features are available in Node (https://node.green/#ES2017). Is this correct?

General setup:
- no server side rendering. All code remains on the server and nothing but data is delivered (via express.js) to the client.

Do you know an example of a Nodejs project on github using ECMA script 2015 or higher? All examples I found are still using 
- ECMA Script 5.1
- or ECMA Script 2015 or higher with Babel.

Thx

Comment: In general, I think it's more helpful to think 'Which ES20XX *features* can I use?' rather than 'Can I use ES20XX?' - it's the version of the specification, not the actual language implementation, and there's no link between Node version numbers and the version of the spec (or in other words, there's no version of Node that is 'the ES2017 version of Node'). Any feature that's green on that site for 8.x should be safe for you to use.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on SO. *All examples I found are still using* - I wonder how you searched, they aren't labeled as 'ES2017 starter project', you'd just expect from a repo that was created the last year that it uses recent Node features. It doesn't make sense to distinguish ES specs like they are different languages because they aren't. async/await is ES2017, and yes, you can use it and the rest of ES2017 features (there are not so many) in Node 8.